# Firebase deploy from github actions using GCP service account key

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, service-accounts, google-iam

```
- id: auth
 name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
 uses: google-github-actions/auth@v0.4.0
 with:
   credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}'
- name: deploy flutter to Firebase
 run: |
   npm install -g firebase-tools
   # firebase login --reauth
   firebase deploy
```

Errror: Failed to get Firebase project xyz. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.

- My GCP service account has roles - Firebase admin,Firebase Develop Admin
- I created a key for my gcp sv account and stored it in Github secrets - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
- I dont want to authenticate using `firebase login:ci` because its soon going to be deprecated
- Its not a permissions issue. I tried giving "owner"  role to sv_account and still getting same error

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you have to add other data under `with:`. Besides `credentials_json`, I also have `project_id` and `service_account` (an email) in my `yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and managed to fix it with the following setup and a custom service account with the "Owner" role:

```
name: Deploy Staging

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  deploy:
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # Install firebase-tools
      - run: yarn global add firebase-tools@12.5.2

      # Install deps
      - run: yarn --frozen-lockfile

      # Authenticate with Google Cloud for firebase
      - name: 'Authenticate with Google Cloud'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
        with:
          credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_STAGING }}'

      # Set the active project
      - run: firebase use staging

      # Deploy staging
      - run: yarn deploy:staging
```